# Send a mail with attachment in java

Tags: jakarta-mail

I want to send mail with attachment in java with the following criteria -

1. The file which I want to attach is a downloadable URL
   (like : http://berkeleycollege.edu/browser_check/samples/excel.xls)
2. Code is deployed on appengine, so Write to File, Create File, Save File is prohibited by google.
3. I don't even have the permission to download the file first and attach it as an attachment.
4. I have tried `InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();` to read the file content pass that to a datahandler. Where url is mentioned above. Sample Code:

   ```
   Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
   Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart();
   MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
   DataHandler handler;
   InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
   handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(input,"xls");
   attachment.setDataHandler(handler);
   multiPart.addBodyPart(attachment);
   msg.setContent(multiPart);
   Transport.send(msg);
   ```
5. Above code is giving `Invalid Content` error.

Is there anyway, I can read the content of that downloadable link and that content can be send as attachment ?

Please share the code snippet for the reference.

Comment: Did you try using [URLDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/URLDataSource.html)?  Exactly what exception are you getting when calling what method?  Can you actually read the InputStream in your program and get the correct data?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually the problem was the file extension. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map model = new HashMap();
                String text = null;
                Properties properties_mail = new Properties();
                InputStream iStream_mail = null;
                String propFileName_mail = "properties/mail.properties";
                InputStream stream_mail =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName_mail);
                properties_mail.load(stream_mail);

                    MimeMessage message = this.javamailsenderImpl.createMimeMessage();
                    MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_RELATED, "UTF-8");
                    mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(properties_mail.getProperty("javaMailSender.username"));
                    mimeMessageHelper.setTo(user.getUserEmail());
                    mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("Bpa Qa Product - New Organisation User");
                    /*String mailBody = "Welcome New User!!! <br /> Your Login Id is : "+user.getUserEmail()+"Your Password is:"+user.getUserPassword();
                    mimeMessageHelper.setText(mailBody, true);*/
                    model.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
                    model.put("userEmail", user.getUserEmail());
                    model.put("userPassword", user.getUserPassword());
                    model.put("organizationName", user.getOrganization().getOrganizationName());
                    model.put("heading", "Thank You for Registering with us .!! Here is your Login credentials.");

                    text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "UserDetails.vm", "UTF-8", model);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setText(new String(text.getBytes(), "UTF-8"), true);

                    this.javamailsenderImpl.send(message);
```